# Same angular directive loading in two view using oclazyload and chunk created by webpack throw Error: [$compile:multidir] Multiple directives

Tags: angularjs, webpack

I am using webpack code split to support lazy loading of modules as per different views defined in my routes. My goal was as below

```
1. Keep all common code in main module and use this as entry file and refer in index.html
2. Then create separate module for each view as chunk and load it as per user navigate to different view using oclazyload
```

It works fine when I load individual view directly. However it throws following error when I load view1, then go to view 2 and then go to view 3. This is happening because view1 and view2 use same angular directive which is not being used by other view. I don't want to define directive in main module until it is not being used for all the views.

```
main.152b3ec….js:7 Error: [$compile:multidir] Multiple directives [datepickercontrol, datepickercontrol] asking for new/isolated scope on:
```

Similar to datepickercontrol, I have many directives which are being used among two or three views max. I just don't want to load these directives in main module bcz it will slow the loading experience for other view which doesn't need these directives.

Please help.

Comment: Did u find any solution for this?

Comment: No, I couldn't find a solution for this :-( Surprise to know that others are also facing this issue. Recently I moved to a different project, therefore couldn't focus on this issue to resolve. Let me know if you have any idea to solve it. We can collaborate.